# How to Modify A Complex Filter Object (For the Purpose of Searching An Array)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to filter my array of objects with multiple match-criteria. I had an example but don't know how to modify the complex object for filtering. **Here's the structure for example:**

```
const filters = {
  size: size => size === 50 || size === 70,
  color: color => ['blue', 'black'].includes(color.toLowerCase()),
  locations: locations => locations.find(x => ['JAPAN', 'USA'].includes(x.toUpperCase())),
  details: details => details.length < 30 && details.width >= 70,
};
```

In my project I want to edit those values dynamically but I need a documentation or suggestion for this.

It's easy to modify simple objects e.g.

```
const filters = {
  color: ['BLUE', 'black'],
  size: [70, 50],
};
```

This is very easy to modify with simple commands (if choosen "blue", add "blue") **but for the first code** I couldn't find the basic way /documentation

Comment: What exactly do you mean by modifying the object?

Comment: You will have to update the whole function : `filters.size = size => size === 65`

Comment: @adiga changing values according to the user input to make a new different search